# Добавление картинки большого размера

Tags: android

Добавляю в Layout-файл `imageView`, в `src` к нему выбираю картинку *heart2.png*. `RootElement` в Layout-файле - `RelativeLayout`. Размер картинки - 1.7МБ.
Приложение содержит несколько Layout-файлов. Когда дохожу до экрана с картинкой - приложение вылетает. 
В **Logcat** записывается:

> 10-25 11:40:27.462 14316-14316/ru.app.toanastasia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-25 11:40:27.462 14316-14316/ru.app.toanastasia E/AndroidRuntime: Process: ru.app.toanastasia, PID: 14316
>   10-25 11:40:27.462 14316-14316/ru.app.toanastasia E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Можете объяснить, в чём проблема, пожалуйста? Существуют какие-либо ограничения на размер вставляемых картинок? Я знаю, что уменьшить размер можно с помощью **Paint.Net**, например, но как быть, если хочется оставить оригинальный размер картинки?

Comment: а какое разрешение картинки?

Comment: А Вы уверены, что ошибка во вставляемой картинке? У Вас ошибка нехватки памяти. И покажите код, в котором Вы вставляете картинку.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала можно переместить картинку в `drawable-nodpi`. Дальше нужно загружать картинку в нужном размере. Как говорит статья [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html),

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

И вот так теперь это можно использовать:

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(
    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, 100, 100));
```

Где `100, 100` - требуемая ширина и высота изображения.